# Is this an herb, weed, or veg?

Tags: identification, diagnosis, vegetables, leaves, weeds

Would like to identify this plant. Which has appeared in my garden and,has grown very fast.I am unable to identify it can someone help.Thank you.[image: mysterious plant]

Comment: Can you share more pictures from the side, and share where you are located in the world?